# Override JWTBearer Auth dependency in FastAPI while testing

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fastapi

I'm having trouble trying to override the JWT validation from my testing stage.

The validation is working fine when calling the API endpoints or when I call them using the Swagger UI.

All my endpoints are declared as follows:

```py
@router.get("/some-path/{id}", response_model=SomeModel, dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())])
async def read_card_basic(*, db: Session = Depends(get_db), id: int):
    # do something
```

And the JWTBearer class has a `__call__` method that perfoms the validation:

```py
async def __call__(self, request: Request):
    credentials: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = await super(JWTBearer, self).__call__(request)
    if credentials:
        if not credentials.scheme == "Bearer":
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Invalid authentication scheme.")
        if not self.verify_jwt(credentials.credentials):
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Invalid or expired token.")
        return credentials.credentials
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Invalid authorization code.")
```

I'm using Pytest and I'm already doing dependencies overriding in the conftest.py file like this:

```py
def pytest_configure() -> None:
    """
    Pytest will identify this function automatically and will run it before running any test
    """
    initialize_testing_db()
    initialize_other_testing_db()

    create_data()
    create_other_data()

    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = get_test_db
    app.dependency_overrides[get_other_db] = get_other_test_db
```

I tried following the examples in the documentation but I can't find a way to remove it since we get the token from an external service and we don't need it during testing.

Any help would be appreciated and I can add more information if needed.

Comment: Have you seen the reference guide for how to override dependencies in a testing context? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/

Answer (score 1):

First, inject the auth dependency as an instance. [Source](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/4497#discussioncomment-2641322)

For example, after your JWTBearer Class add `jwt_bearer = JWTBearer()`

Then, declare your endpoints like:

```py
@router.get("/some-path/{id}", response_model=SomeModel, dependencies=[Depends(jwt_bearer)])
async def read_card_basic(*, db: Session = Depends(get_db), id: int):
    # do something
```

Second, create Class that overrides the behavior of your JWTBearer Class:

```py
class OverrideJWTBearer(JWTBearer):
    async def __call__(self, request: Request):
        return True
```

Finally, on your `conftest.py` override the dependency like this:

```py
app.dependency_overrides[jwt_bearer] = OverrideJWTBearer()
```

Greetings!